# Cannot assign to 'arg' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

Tags: c#

arg is underlined in red where it says arg = localpath
Cannot assign to 'arg' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

```
if (args != null)
{
    foreach (var arg in args)
    {
        //download files locally if needed
        if (!File.Exists(arg))
        {
            try
            {
                var localPath = Helper.DownloadLocally(arg, Helper.ApplicationDirectory);
                arg = localPath;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
        foreach (var arg in args)
        {
            powerShell.AddArgument(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here ?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign to `arg`?

Comment: You are not allowed to change the iterator of a loop when it's running.  Use a different variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to change an item in a loop use a `for` instead, as it doesn't use an enumerator

```
for (var index = 0; index < args.Length; index++)
{

   //download files locally if needed
   if (!File.Exists(args[index]))
   {
      var localPath = Helper.DownloadLocally(args[index], Helper.ApplicationDirectory);
      args[index] = localPath;
   }
```

However you have more going on here

You have a loop in a loop that doesnt make sense

```
foreach (var arg in args)
{
   powerShell.AddArgument(arg);
}
```

What it "seems" (term used loosely) you want to do is

```
var newArgs = args.Select(x => Helper.DownloadLocally(x, Helper.ApplicationDirectory));
foreach (var arg in newArgs)
   powerShell.AddArgument(arg);
```

Comment: I'm going to mark yours as the answer. I've posted my version of the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved my own problem.. Thanks to TheGeneral for posting their version of the answer too.

```
if (args != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(args[i]))
        {
            try
            {
                var localPath = Helper.DownloadLocally(args[i], Helper.ApplicationDirectory);
                args[i] = localPath.ToString(); ;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

    }
    foreach (var arg in args)
    {
            powerShell.AddArgument(arg);
    }
}
```